# Can`t Subtract Weight Paint in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, sculpting

Somehow i can`t find anywhere, nor by pressing CTRL, a way to Subtract the weight paint.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the brush options in the *N* panel (on the right of your 3D view) > *Tool* tab > *Brush* > *Blend*, or in the Properties editor > *Active Tool* tab (the second one) > *Brush* > *Blend*. In *Weight Paint* mode I don't think you can invert the function with any shortcut, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is for sculpting, it would be a nice idea though.

[image]

Comment: I knew i was missing on something very basic, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  allows you to set the Weight dynamically by moving the cursor, as if you would with <kbd>F</kbd>  for radius and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  for Strength.

Comment: Does it?  Says Copied Post to Buffer instead of setting Weight dynamically.